# Populate JQueryUI from database

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. I'm relatively new to the web programming environment; I think I got the gist of the model and controller parts, including repository and unit of work patterns. But I get lost on the client side of things. Say I have this action method in my controller:

```
//I have a Brand table in my Entity framework model
public ActionResult GetBrands()
{
   var result = _unitOfWork.BrandRepository.GetBrands();
   return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm quite lost with Javascript, Ajax and JQueryUI. I made a static JQueryUI selectmenu in my main view (Index.cshtml):

```
<select name="brands" id="brands">
          <option>Brand1</option>
          <option>Brand2</option>
          <option selected="selected">Brand3</option>
          <option>Brand4</option>
          <option>Brand5</option>
</select>
```

How can I invoke my action method to fill the select menu with the brands?

Comment: Just a FYI: You're not populating "jQueryUI", you're populating a normal html select list/dropdown. You probably want to populate the select list using jQuery, and style it using jQueryUI. In fact you might just want to populate the select by passing a model to the view, but that remains to be seen :)

Comment: Nevermind styling, I just want to fill it with data from the model. If I have time left, I'll make it prettier

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have any idea of what the contents of "BrandRepository" is, this is a general answer.

If you're set on populating it using jquery and json, this is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() { //only call when the DOM is ready
   alert('DOM is ready!');
   $.getJSON("/MyController/GetBrands/", function(result) {
      alert('The controller action got hit successfully');
      var options = $("#brands");
      options.html(''); //clears the current options
      alert('The result was: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
      $.each(result, function(i, item) {
         options.append('<option id="' + item.Id + '">' + item.Name '</option>');
      });
   });
});

</script>
```

This assumes that brands is composed of **Id** and **Name** in valid json.

Comment: How do I call it when the DOM is ready? I tried pasting that in several places, but it didn't render anything

Comment: @dario_ramos The first row in the script makes sure it gets called when ready. I guess you've included jQuery in your _Layout file? Just put this script under it in the same file. I'll update the example with a few "debug alerts", so that you know how far it's coming.